# weird errors during migrate from VS 2008 c++ to VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012, migrate

I am porting an existing application with around 40 DLL´s or ActiveX from VS2008 to VS2012. All things seemed to be working but if i end the application some weird exceptions occurred. Some with a simply (currently unused) std::vector which size is about -420 etc. Also there are some weird access-violations. It seemed that if the order how the app destroys some objects is not the same as in 2008.

Has anyone problems like this or some suggestions how to solve such problems ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could show a more concrete example of what you have problems with? We have just finished porting from 2008 to 2012 but it was a lot of work and some changes needed to be done. It helps having klocwork and/or pclint running on the code.

Comment: This is a standard sign of latent heap corruption problems.  That you just haven't discovered in VS2008 but now byte in VS2012.  Which has fairly significant changes in the standard C++ library classes, enabled by C++11.  And uses a different heap.  Also mixing code that was compiled with VS2012 with code that still uses VS2008 compiled code is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: this may help as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I tried not to mixing up 2008 and 2012 by compiling each DLL in batches or solutions within VS 2012.

Comment: I will give klocwork a try but over the years i regularly run severa static code checking tools over our code.

Comment: BTW: I checked all dependencies with the sysinternals dependencywalker which shows no old dll (MFC9.. or something) dependency.

Comment: I made a new solution with all depended projects in it. After recompiling the whole project, it seemed there are no more weird errors.  Thanks for your answers.